# Generating a comma-separated sequence of numbers based on input in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've found more than few things on here to help me as I'm learning to code in Bash and they all come close but not quite.

I need to take an input of a positive integer and print out on a single line down to one, all separated by commas, without a comma at the end of the last variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#countdown

read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter

until ((counter < 1)); do
echo -n ",$counter"
((counter--))
done
```

It almost works out but I can't figure out how to prevent the comma in front and not have it behind the last variable.

EDIT:  You guys are AMAZING.  Poured over this book and learned more in ten minutes here than I did with an hour there.

So is there some sort of command I could use to ensure it was only one number entered and ensure it had to be positive?

Some way to put an if statement on the read to ensure its <= 1 and only one character?

I only have a background in some basic C coding, so I have the basics but translating them to BASH is harder than expected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `seq` with the `-s` option:

```
seq -s, $counter -1 1
```

Comment: Looks like this has the same problem of a trailing comma

Comment: @Kevin: `counter=5; seq -s, $counter -1 1` outputs `5,4,3,2,1` for me.

Comment: `5,4,3,2,1,` (without a newline) for me, on OSX

Comment: The version of `seq` that ships with OS X does seem buggy, although the following hack seems to remove the trailing comma: `seq -s, -t$'\b' 10 1`. The backspace will overwrite the trailing comma.

Comment: This was a HUGE mega help.  Made life so much easier.

Comment: It's not buggy, it just has some implementation differences from gnu equivalents, like all BSD utils.

Answer (score 6):

Probably simper way using [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
#countdown

read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter

eval printf "%s" {${counter}..2}, 1
```

Test:

```
Enter a Number great than 1: 10
10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

To validate the input, you can use regular expressions:

```
#!/bin/bash
#countdown

read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter

if [[ ${counter} =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]
then
  eval printf "%s" {${counter}..2}, 1
fi
```

Comment: Not safe if you don't validate the input value. Consider `counter` having the value `3}; echo arbitrary code; : {3`.

Answer (score 2):

One way

```
read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter
echo -n "$counter"
((counter--))
until ((counter < 1)); do
echo -n ",$counter"
((counter--))
done
```

Comment: +1. It's also possible to do the reverse, using a condition of `((counter <= 1))` and printing `1` after the end of the loop.

Comment: Oooh oooh!  Okay okay so don't actually try to get it to be one statement but instead a ton of smaller statements

Answer (score 1):

A slightly awkward construction using an array, the `seq` command, and a subshell to localize a change to the `IFS` parameter will work.

```
read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter
range=( $(seq $counter -1 1) )
( IFS=,; echo "${range[*]}" )
```

Comment: Hm, kind of pointless, since I forgot about the `-s` option to `seq` and didn't read choroba's answer closely before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way … kinda influenced by [chepner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056346/970195) solution but not using `seq`:

#### Content of script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a Number great than 1: " counter
range=( $(eval echo {$counter..1}) )
( IFS=,; echo "${range[*]}" )
```

#### Test:

```
$ bash script.sh
Enter a Number great than 1: 5
5,4,3,2,1
$ bash script.sh
Enter a Number great than 1: 30
30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```